# Markdown Anchor links can't be clicked twice

Tags: html, github, markdown

I'm writing some documentation using GitHub's built in wiki (using Markdown syntax).

The problem I have had with anchor tags is that once I have clicked that anchor once, manually scrolled down to it again, and try to click it, it won't work anymore.

a) The place where the anchor links jump to.

```
##<a name="listofactions">List of Actions</a>
```

b) An example of an anchor link

```
[Back to List of Actions](#listofactions)
```

I also tried html in markdown syntax

```
<a href="#listofactions">Back to List of Actions</a>
```

And even tried linking to the full url with the # and anchor appended.

```
<a href="https://github.com/Daburu/Daburu-Tools/wiki/API-(DaburuTools.Action)#listofactions">Back to List of Actions</a>
```

They all work, but when I manually scroll down to the anchor link again and click it, it doesn't bring me back to (a) anymore. Unless I click on a different anchor link.

How can I write it such that the anchor links can work regardless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Markdown. This is simply how browsers work. The first time you clink the link (when viewing the same page), the URL in the address bar of your browser changes from `http://example.com/path/to/your/page` to `http://example.com/path/to/your/page#someanchor`. As that is a different URL, the browser will navigate to the new URL by scrolling to the appropriate position on the page. However, as you read the page and scroll to a different position, the URL remains the same. Finally, the second time you click the link,the URL is already `http://example.com/path/to/your/page#someanchor` so there is no change in the URL and as far as the browser is concerned, you are already there so no navigation happens and the page does not scroll.

There may be some JavaScript tricks you can use to trick the browser into behaving as you want, but those won't work on GitHub as they won't let you include any JavaScript in your pages for security reasons.

What you could do as a workaround (assuming you have a long page and want to easily find the specific location again) is first click the **[back]** button (taking you back to `http://example.com/path/to/your/page`) in your browser's navigation bar and then click the **[forward]** button (returning you to `http://example.com/path/to/your/page#someanchor`) which should trigger the browser to navigate to the location and scroll the page.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. Was just wondering if there are any other possible ways other than the workaround. But oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...

<a name="listofactions"></a>

## List of actions
```

Mind the blank line between the HTML tag and the markdown markup.

Then call it via `[link-to-anchor](#listofactions)`

Should work.

Hope to have helped!

Comment: I tried it but the problem still persists. I can click on the anchor link once, but if I click on the anchor link again, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `target="_self"`

Comment: please explain your answer